# Using NI-VISA with Python is too slow

Tags: python, pyvisa

I'm working in Python and using the ctypes package to load visa32.dll to simply write and read instrument, but starting from viWrite to viRead took 510ms(I use NI I/O trace to trace data), 500ms~600ms is too slow for my project and pyVisa is reading too slow too(almost the same time between 500ms~600ms), I don't know how to speed up the execution by python(LabVIEW only need less than 100ms)

```
visa = WinDLL('c:\\windows\\System32\\visa32.dll')
nb = c_uint32()
nb32 = c_uint32()
buff2 = c_uint32()
vi = c_uint32()
AC_Source = b"GPIB0::30::INSTR"
data = b"SOUR:FREQ?"
send_num = len(data)

visa.viOpenDefaultRM(byref(rm_session))
visa.viOpen(rm_session, AC_Source, 0x00, 0x00, byref(vi))
visa.viWrite(vi, data, send_num, byref(nb))
visa.viRead(vi, byref(buff2), 0xFF, byref(nb32))
```

any other way to control the instrument without using PyVISA or any way that can make it faster?
I'm new to ctypes, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider [PyVISA](https://pypi.org/project/PyVISA/).  Probably no faster, but better than reinventing the wheel with ctypes, esp. if you are new at it.

Comment: What specifically is the piece of equipment? in some causes the equipment will not respond until it has "completed" it's task or a measurement loop. Additionally you can get better transfer rate over usb for some product as the gpib bus can be slow for large transfer of binary data.